# upload canvas drawing to mysql db using php as an image

Tags: php

Hy guys. I want to take a drawing from a canvas instead of saving it as an image like this https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js .I want to upload it to my local server mysql using php.

please help

```
<?php 

$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","userdetails");

$results = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM userInfo"); 

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){

     echo "Name :".$row['uname'].
          "<br/>Surname : ".$row['surname'].
          "<br/> Image : <img width='200' height='100' src='images/".$row['userImage']."' />"; 
 }

 @$uname = $_POST['uname'];
 @$surname = $_POST['surname'];
 @$image = $_POST['img']; 

if(isset($uname)){ 

    $conn->query("INSERT INTO userInfo values('','$uname','$surname','$image')");
    move_uploaded_file($image, '../images/'.basename($image));

 }

?>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far and where you'd need help?

Comment: I dont know how I will get the file and upload it to the project at the same time storing the file name to the database. My target its to take a picture from my webcam using javascript and send that path of the image to php from there I will upload the URL of the image and push the file it self to the files on the project. But now I cant get the image because I didnt save it. SO I want to jump that stage of saving the image and just upload it to the database as I click the button save after taking the picture from the Webcam to the canvas

Comment: @MelB: ... please place that code in the question and format it for readability. [and then delete that comment with the code]

Comment: Done @Paul T...